# PHP random set of images

Tags: php, random, rotation

I'm using a php script to randomly show images. I've duplicated this script three times because I wanted to show three random images at once - I'm unsure of how to change the php code to show 3 images.

The problem is, I don't want to run into the chance of all three scripts showing the same images at once. Is there something that I could add to this code to make sure that each image displayed is always different?

```
<?php 
$random = "random.txt"; 
$fp = file($random); 
srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
$rl = $fp[array_rand($fp)]; 
echo $rl; 
?>
```

the html:

```
 <?php include("rotate.php"); ?>
 <?php include("rotate.php"); ?>
 <?php include("rotate.php"); ?>
```

*the random.txt just has a list of filenames with links.

Comment: google `$random = "random.txt";  $fp = file($random);  srand((double)microtime()*1000000);  $rl = $fp[array_rand($fp)];  echo $rl; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_rand()` to select more than one random key at a time, like this:

```
$random = "random.txt";
$fp = file($random);
shuffle($fp);
// You don't need this. The array_rand() function
// is automatically seeded as of 4.2.0
// srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
$keys = array_rand($fp, 3);
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++):
    $rl = $fp[$keys[$i]]; 
    echo $rl;
endfor;
```

This would eliminate the need for including the file multiple times. It can all be done at once.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I really like that I don't need to include the file three times! :D

Answer (score 5):

Simple solution...

1. Get the array of random images (you already did this)
2. Shuffle the array
3. Pop an image off the end of the array whenever you need one

rotate.php

```
$random = "random.txt"; 
$fp = file($random); 
shuffle($fb); //randomize the images
```

in your code

```
<?php include('rotate.php') ?>
```

Whenever you need an image

```
<?php echo array_pop( $fb ) ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

Answer (score 2):

```
function GetRandomItems($arr, $count)
{
    $result = array();
    $rcount = 0;
    $arrsize = sizeof($arr);
    for ($i = 0; ($i < $count) && ($i < $arrsize); $i++) {
        $idx = mt_rand($rcount, $arrsize);
        $result[$rcount] = trim($arr[$idx]);
        $arr[$idx] = $arr[$rcount];
        $rcount++;
    }
    return $result;
}

$listname = "random.txt";
$list = file($listname);
$random = GetRandomItems($list, 3);
echo implode("<BR>", $list);
```

P.S. Actually, Galen's answer is better. For some reason I forgot about shuffle xD

Answer (score 1):

You could write a recursive function to check if the array ID has already been printed, and if  it has, call itself again. Just put that in a for loop to print three times :)

Though keep in mind that truly `random` images could overlap!

```
$beenDisplayed = array();

function dispRand($id) {
    if (in_array($id, $beenDisplayed)) {
        //generate random number
        dispRand($id);
    }
    else {
        array_push($beenDisplayed, $id);
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    dispRand($random_id);
}
```

Comment: a recursive functions seems a little overcomplicated for this task

Comment: @Galen maybe, but I've never heard of `shuffle` :P